# Block pages for non logged in users with the AuthComponent in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Here is my project :

I have a website that can be used by a user or an admin.
I created methods such as index, view,... These views have to be accessible for users and admin. 
I also have methods such as admin_index, admin_edit. They have to be viewd by admin.

For the moment all users pages are publics and admin pages are protected by the login. I would like to ask for a login for users pages too.The only public page will be **/users/login**.

How can I do that with the AuthComponent?

When I type that :

```
public function beforeFilter() { 
   $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
```

I have a redirection loop.

Thank you for your help

---

I still have the problem. Here is my code.

AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Text', 'Form', 'Html', 'Session', 'Cache');

    public $components = array(
        'Session', 
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction'   => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true),
            'logoutRedirect'=> array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
        )
    );


    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }
}
```

And my UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow(array('login', 'logout'));
    }

    public function login(){

        if(isset($_SESSION['Auth']['User'])){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }

        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Identifiants incorrects', 'notif');
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Vous êtes déconnecté', 'notif', array('type' => 'success'));
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

I still have redirection loop. I don't understand why.

Comment: `beforeFiler` Is that a typo just in this post or your code - it should be `beforeFilter`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use ACL, however, if you still want to just use the AuthComponent I would suggest using the beforeFilter() as you are but in addition I would add a is logged in check here as well such as:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }else{
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }
}
```

If you still want to go further using just the AuthComponent you could have more checks setup such as:

```
    // group_id = 2 is for users who are paid subscribers for example
    // and group_id = 1 is for administrators
    if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == 1){
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }elseif($this->Auth->user('group_id') == 2 ){
        $this->Auth->allow('paidcontent','video','photo','etc');
    }elseif($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    }else{
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }
```

The code above is not tested. If you need any further help, please let me know

Comment: I found the problem. I create the user's menu with a controller and an action. I forgot to allow the action.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with this code as well:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $helpers = array('Text', 'Form', 'Html', 'Session', 'Cache');

    public $components = array(
        'Session', 
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction'   => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
            // Change controller = index to controller = users
            //'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true),
            'logoutRedirect'=> array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
        )
    );


    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Still does not work.
When I type http://mywebsite.com/, it redirects to http://mywebsite.com/users/login/ and I have a redirection loop. I don't understant why there is the redirection loop because I allowed the login action.